# How to use a case statement to determine which field to left join on

Tags: mysql, left-join, case

I have a query that needs to be able to left join a field at the right place given the condition that the field is equal to a variable.

Something like:

```
CASE WHEN challenges.userID = $var
LEFT JOIN challengesRead ON challenges.userID = challengesRead.userID
CASE WHEN challenges.opponentID = $var
LEFT JOIN challengesRead ON challenges.opponentID = challengesRead.userID
```

I think I am on the right track but I'm not sure how to put the query together.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this may work

```
LEFT JOIN challengesRead 
ON challenges.userID = CASE 
WHEN challenges.userID = $var THEN challengesRead.userID 
WHEN challenges.opponentID = $var THEN challenges.opponen END
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want this:

```
LEFT JOIN challengesRead 
  ON CASE WHEN challenges.userID = $var
            THEN challenges.userID 
          WHEN challenges.opponentID = $var
            THEN challenges.opponentID
     END = challengesRead.userID
```

which can be simplified to:

```
LEFT JOIN challengesRead 
  ON $var = challengesRead.userID
  AND ( challenges.userID = $var
     OR challenges.opponentID = $var
      )
```